# Как придумать оптимальное хранение данных MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица пользователей, есть таблица данных (скажем таблица с рандомными числами от 1 до 1000).
Задача такая: каждый пользователь может выбрать от 1 до 100 любых чисел из таблицы с данными и записать в свой кабинет. Как правильно организовать хранение этой записи.
Из того что первое пришло в голову

```
userid (int) | data (text)
user1        | 8234, 81123, 1234
user2        | 903452, 12312341, 1234, 903, 912, 1324, 892354
```

И потом когда нужно вытащить выборку, просто разбивать по запятой.
Кто знает более элегантное решение?

Comment: Используйте связь многие-ко-многим (через доп. таблицу)

Comment: делаете вторую таблицу в которой две колонки, userid и data. причем в поле data лежит только одно число. каждое число - отдельная запись

Comment: Блин, Вы гений! Спасибо.

Comment: – Андрей, напишите ответ, приму его как готовый.

Comment: ManyToMany тут более предпочтителен ввиду более высокой производительности, а в некоторых случаях даже меньше места будет занимать.